# Change selector color of a Preference

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-theme

I couldn't find any info related.

I have implemented my custom theme with Android-holo-colors assets in the rest of my app without any problems, until I began developing the PreferenceActivity.

I just can't find how can I change the selector color of any preference, it's remains the default value (Holo-blue).

Any ideas?

Thanks BTW.

**EDIT:**
I tried to set the main theme in the Activity label at the Manifest, but does not worked for me. I presume that is because I didn't specify nothing that overwrites any Preference style, but that's my problem, I don't know which ones I have to overwrite.

Comment: You have to set the theme for the preference activity in your manifest.

Comment: Does not worked for me =S

Comment: You might show what you're doing that's not working.  You would have to theme the list selector specifically.  Unless the preference activities can't be themed but I wouldn't think that's the case.

Comment: I've updated the question. BTW I know how to set the style to normal Activities, but in the Preferences ones, I'm not able to set it by xml (with attributes like "android:background" or "style") and i don't know if it's posible to do it programatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `PreferenceActivity` `onCreate`, after you have added your preferences, call:

```
getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.your_selector);
```